# Ember.js: Using a computed property in handlebars from a Service

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-properties

So I have this computed property inside my `component.js`: `contexts: Ember.computed.oneWay('myService.contexts'),`

And I am able to get the content from another action

```
 openHelp(){
      console.log(this.get('contexts'))
      alert(this.get('contexts'))
    }
  }
```

But when I try to use the computed property in Handlebars (`{{contexts}}`) it's just blank.

I created an Ember Twiddle for this question: https://ember-twiddle.com/38de64d58dcf3298df6d4176f15cbc0e?openFiles=components.my-component-help.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component-help.hbs

If I have an array `foo: [ 'foo','bar']` and I do {{foo}} it outputs in handlebars. But if I make `foo` a computed property that gets `[ 'foo','bar']` from and do `{{foo}}` I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: https://ember-twiddle.com/e9c2ef05e27013a389e0b2bfdaec3d40?openFiles=services.my-service.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component-help.hbs

There were two issues:

1. `contexts` is an array. When you `console.log` or `alert` it, those methods internally in some browsers `JSON.stringify` the object for you for your convenience. Ember will not do that. You need to format the array yourself or, as I did, `each` over it. For debugging purposes, feel free to use the `log` helper.
2. Computed properties on arrays are watching for array mutations through Ember's methods such as `pushObject` and `removeObject`. Simply using `push` or `splice` won't update the computed property.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on the above answer which is correct because I don't have enough reputation, but I wanted to add a link to the documentation relating to Ember's observable methods for enumerables:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/enumerables/